# XML Output Shows Side-By-Side

Tags: php, html, css, xml, echo

I have a geolocation api that works using XML, here's example: http://freegeoip.net/xml/31.44.188.50

I used this XML api on my website so I make a geo-location scanner, but for some reasons when it output, the IP/Country/Zip Code etc.. it shows side by side, which is confusing, my question is how to get the output to be below each other or in table.

My code:

```
    <input type="text" name="username" style="text-align: center;" placeholder=" IP address" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="" value="Resolve" />
```

.`

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$name = $_POST['username'];
$blacklist = array("100.100.100","123.123.123");
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
if(in_array($name,$blacklist))
{
    echo "No";
else
$api1 = file_get_contents("http://freegeoip.net/xml/$name");
echo "<div style='display: block; color: red; font-weight: bold;>'  $api1  </div>";


}
}

?>
```

That's how it looks:  **31.44.188.50 NL Netherlands 07 Noord-Holland Amsterdam 52.35 4.9167**

That's how I want it:

- IP address: **31.44.188.50**
- Country: **NL Netherlands**
- City: **Noord-Holland Amsterdam**

etc

Comment: You'll have to read the content of the files with an extension or a library such a DOM document or SimpleXML to do that easily. Google them, they are really easy to use on read tasks

Comment: @ClémentMalet Hello, Thanks for your feedback, can you do it for me please and modify the code using SimpleXML so it can show in a table? Because I have no idea how this can be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using SimpleXML :

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://freegeoip.net/xml/31.44.188.50");
echo 'IP : ', $xml->Ip, '<br>';
echo 'Country code : ', $xml->CountryCode, '<br>';
echo 'Country name : ', $xml->CountryName, '<br>';
echo 'City : ', $xml->City, '<br>';
```

Output :

```
IP : 31.44.188.50
Country code : NL
Country name : Netherlands
City : Amsterdam
```

More example and explanations on the documentation : 
http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php